# No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "int" but the matching candidate does exist

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, janino

I want to add some code inside the Spark-SQL generated java code. So I create a jar file that has a class "Employee" and manually insert 'Employee e = new Employee(some integer)' in the file: sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/WholeStageCodegenExec.scala.
When invoking spark-shell, I did 'spark-shell --jars /path/to/myJar.jar'. However, when I run the query, it reports this error:
ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 21, Column 18: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "int"; candidates are: "Employee()", "Employee(int)", "Employee(java.lang.String)"

Most similar questions I found online are because the parameter type mismatch, however, I do have Employee(int) constructor as you can see here, why Janino still complained about it??

My Employee example is pretty simple:

```
public class Employee {
  String name = "Default";
  int age;
  int ID;

  Employee() {
    System.out.println("Empty constructor");
  }

  Employee(String myName) {
    name = myName;
  }

  Employee(int myAge) {
    age = myAge;
  }

  void sayHi() {
    System.out.println("Hello, I'm " + name);
  }

  void sayhello() {
    System.out.println("Hello,test");
  }
}
```

And the modified generated code is also simple as:

```
public void init(int index, scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs) {
  String name = "Go";
  int age = 30;
  Employee e1 = new Employee(age);
  e1.sayHi();
```

Really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: I tried to all different kinds of Employee constructors but all failed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Spark codegen, but it's one issue with the Java code.

All constructors of the Employee class are decrared with the [default access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6), so they are not accessible from the other packages. Try to declare constructor with `public` modifier.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is the problem.